# Android O: Service.stopForeground equivalent

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I'm currently trying to make some kind of music player app. For playback I created a separate service. Because I want to keep it playing all the time, I'm calling Service.startForeground(). While compiling for Android O (SDK level 27) I have to use Context.startForegroundService() due to Androids "new" background execution limits.

This works fine, but when the user pauses playback, I want the notification to be dismissable. In the past, I was able to call stopForeground(), but this has no effect on Android O. Is there any other way to switch between background and foreground service or any other chance to implement this behaviour? Apps like Google Play Music are using exactly this notification pattern, but how do they do it?

Comment: Which flag do you pass in `stopForeground()` ?

Comment: My fault. I was using `stopForeground(boolean: removeNotification)`. With flag `STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH` it does work. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to suggest it. Good to know you figured it out

Comment: You should put it as answer, rather than updating in question.

Comment: what class declares STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happened because I used the wrong method. You have to use `stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)` instead of `stopForeground(true)`.

Comment: In Xamarin code: StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove); // true = Remove not Detach.
From Service: public unsafe void StopForeground(bool removeNotification)

Answer (score 3):

```
stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE)
```

Use this in case you want remove notification too

Answer (score 1):

Use

> stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)

instead of

> stopForeground(true)

Answer (score -2):

I got the same issue and tried many solution but later on i got to know that i have given some permission in AndroidManifest.xml file which were of no use, when i commented them it was working fine

> The commented permission are as following

```
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> -->
```

Comment: I don't think those permissions has anything to do with this question.